# PHP Catchable fatal error: Object of class DateTime could not be converted to string

Tags: php

I am trying to generate (after 7 months date from now) date:

Here is my code and it is working fine in another php file in the same site

```
$cdate = new DateTime("+7 months");
$cdate->modify("-" . ($cdate->format('j')-1) . " days");
$ex= $cdate->format('Y-m-d');
$ex = strtotime($ex);
```

but this code return this error

> PHP Catchable fatal error:  Object of class DateTime could not be
>   converted to string

any suggestions please?

Comment: Please do not post duplicates like this. If you need to update your existing answer, you can edit it.